# Doctrine QueryBuilder not returning all rows for JOIN and WHERE IN query

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm, shopware

I'm writing a Shopware plugin, and I have the following code to build an SQL query:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->container->get('dbal_connection')->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('a.articleID', 'v.optionID', 'v.value')
        ->from('s_filter_articles', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('a', 's_filter_values', 'v', 'a.valueID = v.id')
        ->where('a.articleID IN (:ids)')
        ->andWhere('v.optionID IN (3, 8)')
        ->orderBy('a.articleID, v.optionID')
        ->setParameter(':ids', $relatedIds);
```

The built SQL string is the following, according to `$queryBuilder->getSql()`:

```
SELECT a.articleID, v.optionID, v.value 
FROM s_filter_articles a LEFT JOIN s_filter_values v ON a.valueID = v.id 
WHERE (a.articleID IN (:ids)) AND (v.optionID IN (3, 8)) 
ORDER BY a.articleID, v.optionID ASC
```

When I replace ":ids" with "1,2,3,4,5" and execute the query, all rows get returned as expected. (I made sure that $relatedIds is "1,2,3,4,5", too.)

When I execute the query in PHP (via `$queryBuilder->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`), only results for the first ID (1) are returned. `var_dump($result)`shows the following:

```
array(1) { [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["optionID"]=> string(1) "3" ["value"]=> string(13) "Schwarz Kombi" } [1]=> array(2) { ["optionID"]=> string(1) "8" ["value"]=> string(7) "Schwarz" } } }
```

Why is this not returning results for other IDs (2,3,4,5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a real array in

```
->setParameter(':ids', $relatedIds);
```

for example

```
$relatedIds = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I just found out myself, but I will mark your answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that $relatedIds is a string, so setParameter(':ids', $relatedIds) inserted it with quotes

> WHERE a.articleID IN ('1,2,3,4,5')

instead of

> WHERE a.articleID IN (1,2,3,4,5)

I need to pass an array instead of a string to achieve what I want.

Additionally, it is necessary to pass a type to setParameter:

```
setParameter(':ids', $relatedIds, \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);
```